# cannot load such file -- pty (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

Completely new to Ruby on Rails.  My environment is Windows 2008 R2, and I just use the 
RailsInstaller to set it up.  I was given a website, so I placed it under C:\Sites.
I followed the guide, and installed rails, as you can see the version down there in the code. 
Then I ran "rails server" to try to start the service, but I was given error message about "therubyracer-heroku-0.8.1.pre3 not installed, so I did a gem install and bundle install after that.  Then therubyracer-heroku threw bunch of error, so I looked that up, told me I need to wrap it in a group, which I did and removed from production group within the gem file.  Now when I do a "bundle install" everything is good, so I proceed with "rails server" and I got the error message down below.  Any help ?  please

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

gem 'pg'
gem 'hashie'
gem 'figaro' # handles app configurations
gem 'airbrake' # exception/error tracking service
gem 'haml'
gem 'validates_existence', '>= 0.4'
gem 'useragent'
gem 'heroku'

group :development do
    gem 'zeus' # speeds up loading of console and server
    gem 'better_errors' # nicely-formatted UI of errors
    gem 'binding_of_caller' # allows real-time debugging on error breakpoints
    gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby, :require => 'v8'
end

group :production do

end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
end

gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.5'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'prototype-rails'
gem 'coffee-filter'
```

-The Error output

```
    Rails 3.2.13
    ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15) [i386-mingw32]

    $ rails server
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
    tive_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- pty (LoadError)

    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from c:/Sites/rct/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `zeus` gem requires Linux or Mac OS X See https://github.com/burke/zeus

Remove the zeus gem from your Gemfile, run `bundle install`, and then retry `rails server`

Comment: Removed. But what about the activesupport or bundler or railties , is this a path issue with windows ?

Comment: No, all three of these gems are fine