# `rails s` says "`require': cannot load such file -- pty (LoadError)" in Windows RailsInstaller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railsinstaller, railsinstaller-windows

I have just installed RailsInstaller on my Windows 10 PC. I am not able to run `rails s` or `rails g controller StaticPages home help`.

I have also tried to fix this by installing the zeus gem as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978412/cannot-load-such-file-pty-loaderror) related StackOverflow question but had no success.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '4.2.2'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',     '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'pry-nav', group: [:development, :test]

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '>= 1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Errors:

```
rails s
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console/slave.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- pty (LoadError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console/slave.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console.rb:13:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
        from c:/Sites/sample_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backtrace tells us that the web-console gem wants Ruby's pty library. Unfortunately [PTYs (pseudo-terminals)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) are a Unix/Linux feature which does not exist on Windows, so that Ruby library doesn't either.

You can get moving in a couple of ways:

- If you don't care about the web-console gem right now, just remove it from your Gemfile.
- If you really need the web-console gem, try replacing web-console with these gems:

  ```
  gem 'rubysl-pty', platforms: :ruby
  gem 'web-console-rails3', platforms: :ruby
  ```

  Source: [a web-console Github issue](https://github.com/rails/web-console/issues/19).

Comment: I have removed the webconsole. Now I have got another error. Should I update this question or ask new question? 

`c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:182:in `rescue in create_default_data_source': No source of timezone data could be found. (TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound)`

Comment: I'd go with a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue by following below steps:

1. First check your Gemfile.lock, if you have mentioned bcrypt version over there then you don't need to mention the bcrypt version in Gemfile.
2. If bcrypt version is missing in the Gemfile.lock then in the perform following steps:
   a) gem install bcrypt
   b) Open your Gemfile and paste "gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'"
   c) run command in console : bundle install

I hope by following above given steps might solve your problem.